# The exact meaning of [offset someData] in assembly language

Tags: assembly, offset, memory-address

My question is about OFFSET in assembly language

I have written code below :(emu8086)

```
data segment
DATA1  dw 6
DATA2 dw 5
ends

stack segment
dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:

mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax



mov bx, [offset DATA1]
mov ax, [offset DATA2]


mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
int 21h    
ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

I excepted when I type `[offset DATA1]` I receive 6 and when I type `[offset DATA2]` I receive 5.

My reason was this : `offset` gives us the address of a data and this sign`[]` give us the content of the mentioned place of memory. so when we use `[offset data1]` we should receive data1 (here is 6)

But the result is some thing else. after running this code ax is 0006H and bx is 0000H and I can't understand why.

can anyone please help me to understand the meaning of `[offset someData]`?

I know It is very basic but I'm new in assembly.

Thanks in advance for your attention

Answer (score 0):

I tried to assemble your code with TASM and received BX=0 and AX=2 as expected:

```
cs:0000 B88F4E         mov    ax,4E8F
cs:0003 8ED8           mov    ds,ax
cs:0005 8EC0           mov    es,ax
cs:0007 BB0000         mov    bx,0000
cs:000A B80200         mov    ax,0002
cs:000D B8004C         mov    ax,4C00
cs:0010 CD21           int    21
```

In most assemblers, **MOV reg,variable** will load the reg with offset of variable and **MOV reg,[variable]** with the variable contens. This was not the case of MASM, which interprets **MOV reg,variable** as loading reg with memory-variable contents and you had to explicitely write **MOV reg,OFFSET variable** to load the offset part of variable address. Your syntax is mixed up and it is the business of used assembler whether it will parse
**MOV reg,[offset variable]** as offset or as contents or generate some warning. 
Omitt the word **offset** if you want to load the contents of DATAx. You may also have to specify **ASSUME DS:data** to tell your assembler that you have loaded DS register with segment address.